# Can grep be used on a Perl variable?

Tags: perl, grep

Is it possible one way or another to, within a Perl script, effectively execute grep against a Perl variable? An equivalent Perl function would be equally acceptable, I just want to keep the solution as simple as possible.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/bin/grep

$var="foobar";

$newvar="system('grep -o "foo" $var');

sprintf $newvar;
```

Where I expect `sprintf $newvar` to output `foo`.

Would also welcome any feedback on best practice here. I am not extremely familiar with Perl.

Comment: I can't recommend the book Learning Perl enough.  It is well written and does an excellent job explaining the basics.  Take a look here: http://books.google.com/books?id=4pINCzVk9NMC&lpg=PP1&dq=Learning%20Perl&client=firefox-a&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just use regex matching in Perl. No need to call external "grep" command.

```
$var =~ /foo/;
```

please read documentation [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) for introduction on how to search for patterns in variables. Also of interest is Perl's own [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
$var="foobar";
if ( $var =~ /foo/){
  print "found foo\n";
}
```

Comment: As in the example, the text that I want to "grep" is already contained within a variable. So would your suggestion become `$newvar = $var =~ /foo/;` or am I misunderstanding? Also, no particular reason that I wanted to use grep other than that I am familiar with it already.

Comment: `$newvar` will contain return value of the search if `foo` is found.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I know enough to be dangerous, but not enough to know what I am looking for. :) I can accomplish what I am looking for now.